# Integral of Cosine(z) for z complex

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, trigonometry

Trying to integrate 
$$\int \cos(z)\mathrm dz$$ where z is a complex number. What is a good way to do so?

Book gives
$$\oint \frac{\operatorname{Cos}(z)}{\left ( z-a \right )^{m}}dz=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\oint \frac{a_{k}\left ( z-a \right )^{k}}{k!\left ( z-a \right )^{m}}dz=2 \pi i\frac{a_{m-1}}{\left ( m-1 \right )!}$$

Comment: You'd first have to define indefinite integrals of complex variables, but any sensible definition will still give you $\sin z$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ...give or take a constant.

Comment: It still gives you $\sin z$ :) I didn't say it only gives you $\sin z$. :) @FlybyNight

Comment: Oh right, so it could give $\sin z + \cos z + \tanh z$?

Answer (score 3):

As an indefinite integral, it's exactly the same procedure as with a real variable. $\int \cos z\;dz = \sin z + C$ where $C$ is an arbitrary (complex) constant.

Comment: It's certainly what the OP want's to prove.

Comment: My book says$$\oint \frac{Cos(z)}{\left ( z-a \right )^{m}}dz=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\oint \frac{a_{k}\left ( z-a \right )^{k}}{k!\left ( z-a \right )^{m}}dz=2 \pi i\frac{a_{m-1}}{\left ( m-1 \right )!}$$
It's a close integral of a pole of order m.

Comment: this is something totally different